# Google maps api v3, bus stops mouse over info

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps api v3 to show shops selling our products on map by adding custom markers. There are visible icons of public transport stops (bus, tram, etc.) on the map but the info of what line number stop there is not showing when mouse over such icon. (The info shows when I check the same place on normal google map) Is is possible to turn it on on my map too?

Answer (score 0):

Google embeds clickable points of interest in the map, with their own info.

If you add your own marker, you still need to add your desired info to that marker, then set an event listener on the mouseover event to display an infobox, and append the marker info to a nicely formatted html into that infobox.

A simpler way would be to set the title property of the marker, that will by default show up on mouseover, but it'll be just some text.

You could use the google places api that comes as a module of google maps library to find those transit stops and parse the place details, but that's way ahead in the learning curve.

Comment: That is probably not the info I am looking for. I am adding my own info to my markers, thats not the case. I just need to let people check what bus/tram is going around my markers. See the img here [link](http://bezlepkova.com/gmap.png) (normal google map on the right)

Comment: You mean, I misunderstood the question? Can you elaborate or provide an example to try and be of help?